# MySql - Out of Range error 1264 for empty table

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to change the data type of some rows to DECIMAL(3,2) in mySql workbench.
There are no elements in the database, but when I try to synchronizise the Model I get the following message:

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1264: Out of range value
>   for column 'länge' at row 1

SQL Code:

```
    ALTER TABLE `technical_center`.`Form` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `länge` `länge` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL ,
    CHANGE COLUMN `breite/durchmesser` `breite/durchmesser` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed
>       Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>       Nothing to fetch`

With the datatype `VARCHAR` I don't have any Problems.
What I don't understand, is why I get a out of range error, when I don't even have any values in my schema.[DB-Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpKGm.png)

Comment: What did form look like before you tried to change it?

Comment: Same structure, but with INT values